# Rails server won't start after bundle update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thin, ruby-1.9.3

I ran bundle update and now my server is throwing the following error:

```
rails s
/Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `rescue in rescue in block in require': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `rescue in block in require'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /Users/toptier/Desktop/Projects/bestapp/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:31:in `require'
from script/rails:31:in `<main>'
```

The line application.rb:9 is :

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

This are my list of gems:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'pg'

gem 'thin'
gem 'eventmachine'
group :development do
   gem 'ruby-debug-base19'
   gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do

   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

   # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    #  gem 'therubyracer'

   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem "rails_config"
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'em-http-request'
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3' 
gem 'aws-sdk';

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'imgkit'
gem 'websnap'

gem 'randumb'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'annotate', 
:git => 'git://github.com/jeremyolliver/annotate_models.git', 
:branch => 'rake_compatibility'

gem 'tinymce-rails'

gem 'mail'
```

The server is Thin

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try running

```
bundle exec rails s
```